# JS Changing CSS Height Using Variable

Tags: javascript, css, web, frontend, web-frontend

I have made a script that takes the height of two elements and if one is smaller than the other, will adjust the height accordingly to match. Going off the console log it is doing and recognising everything as expected except changing the elements height, which I presume is due to it being stored as a variable? Any help appreciated.

```
console.log('Start of script.');

let divElement = document.getElementById("basic-calendar-card");
let style = window.getComputedStyle(divElement);
let height = style.getPropertyValue("height");

console.log('Basic calendar height = ' + height);

let divElementTwo = document.getElementById("list-calendar-card");
let styleTwo = window.getComputedStyle(divElementTwo);
let heightTwo = styleTwo.getPropertyValue("height");

console.log('List calendar height = ' + heightTwo);

if (height < heightTwo) {
  console.log('List calendar is bigger.')
  divElement.style.height = heightTwo;
} else if (heightTwo < height) {
  console.log('Basic calendar is smaller.')
  divElementTwo.style.height = height;
} else {
  console.log('Same size.')
}

console.log('End of script.');
```

Comment: Actually, it does add the height property to the element. It is probably a collision with some other CSS properties you have set somewhere. If I used your code on a clean slate, it worked like expected.

Comment: Just try to set some css styles in developer console to make the two calendars equal in height. Seems like you got the wrong CSS in place.

Comment: probally your css was rewriting your javascript code.

Comment: @naxsi That would be amazing, CSS writing Javascript :D

Comment: @Randy the css code that javascript has generating, my english is very bad and wrong, so...

Comment: The `box-sizing` CSS property defaults to `content-box`, which doesn't include any border or padding.
e.g.: `height: 100, padding: 20, border: 10` results in a computed height of 100 + 2 * (20 + 10) = 160 and the content's height remains 100
`border-box`, on the other hand, includes both borders and paddings.
e.g.: `height: 100, padding: 20, border: 10` results in a computed height of 100 while the content's height is reduced to 100 - 2 * (20 + 10) = 40
If you have any border or padding in place you need to set `box-sizing: border-box;` on both elements.